# jquery selecting "parents"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I have the following:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h3>Title</h3><!-- I want to select this --> 
    <a name="anchor-name"></a>
    <div class="section">
        <h4>Sub section</h4>
        <a name="subsection-name"></a> <!-- this is selected -->
        <div class="subsection"></div>
    </div>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <a name="anchor-name"> </a>
    <div class="section">
        <h4>Sub section</h4>
        <a name="subsection-name"></a> 
        <div class="subsection"></div>
    </div>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <a name="anchor-name"></a>
    <div class="section">
        <h4>Sub section</h4>
        <a name="subsection-name"></a> 
        <div class="subsection"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have the anchor selected (as indicated) how do I access the `<h3>Title</h3>`? I want to get the nearest "parent h3"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before we go any further it's worth noting that the `h3` is *not* a parent of the `a` element. However, the following should select the `h4`, assuming consistent HTML structure:

```
$(this).closest('div.section').prevAll('h3:first');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6p6FB/).

Incidentally, if the this snippet of HTML is contained within another element, to give:

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
    <h3>Title</h3>
             <a name="anchor-name"></a>
             <div class="section">
                    <h4>Sub section</h4>
                    <a name="subsection-name"></a> // this is selected
    <!-- ...other stuff... -->
</div>
```

Then it'd be easiest to use:

```
$(this).closest('.contentWrapper').find('h3');
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).
- `siblings()`.

Comment: Well, that explains why "parent" wasn't working (duh). I do however have an issue as now for some reason it's selecting ALL my h3 tags...see my code above...?

Comment: Yeah, I've amended the code from using `siblings()` to use `prevAll('h3:first')` which *should* avoid that issue. Also, I've added a demo to show how to use it.

Comment: I apologize I should have provided more detail in the first place

Answer (score 1):

The h3 isn't a parent, its a child within a parent object, whats "containing" the h3?

Imagine it is another div, with an id of main-holder.. and that the selected a is $(this):

$h3 = $(this).parent("#mainholder").children("h3")

Answer (score -1):

Use the jQuery [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) function;

```
$("a[name=subsection-name]").closest("h3");
```

Comment: The selected `a` element is not a descendant of the `h3`.